# Can the python "request" module's response perform Submit?

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, form-submit

Im trying to avoid a javascript heavy page and avoid using Selenium. I have an Okta instance that I've managed to power futz thru.

To SAML/SSO sign into an app.

Their guide at https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/session-cookie/overview/#retrieving-a-session-cookie-by-visiting-an-application-embed-link mentions that you will receive content like so:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="appForm" action="https://sp.example.com/auth/saml20" method="POST">
            <input name="SAMLResponse" type="hidden" value="SnippedForBrevity"/>
            <input name="RelayState" type="hidden" value="/some/deep/link"/>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">

          $(function(){
            document.getElementById('appForm').submit();
          });
      </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can confirm I've received content similar to this in response (class/type is *requests.models.Response*, which returned from a Requests.post() call). One thing I've noticed is that in a browser this automatically submits and then loads the page due to **document.getElementById('appForm').submit()**

As the title says I'm doing this with the python requests module, and have this content but I cant figure out how to do the "submit" against the same response object that has the HTML. If this makes any sense, how can I do this with requests?

Comment: in the browser, when nanually submitting, do you notice an additional POST request generated in the web traffic (via dev tools > network tab)?

Comment: So after this suggestion. I did wait a bit longer in the Browser and look at the HAR capture on the process and I see their is redirect and the next POST is on the different domain. Looking at that, Im presuming I may be able to POST the SAML directly to that domain and not worry about javscripting it. So once I have a moment I will test that out.

Comment: I was on vacation. Though I figured out a way to get the SAML response code in a form from return HTML content. I think I can use the Session.post() module to send it and should be good to go thanks